# Passing vector of structs as function argument asks for allocator

Tags: c++

I have a struct :

```
    struct ShaderMacroStruct{
    std::string macro;
    std::string value;
    ShaderMacroStruct():macro(""),value("")
    {}
};
```

I have a method which has one of its parameters the vector of the structs (defined above):

```
GLuint MakeSeparableProgram(GLenum shaderType,  std::string &shaderText ,std::vector< ShaderMacroStruct> &shadersMacroList);
```

But when passing all the parameters I am getting the following compilation error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "my_namespace::MakeSeparableProgram" matches the argument list
argument types are: (int, const std::string, 
                     std::vector<my_namespace::ShaderMacroStruct, 
                     std::allocator<my_namespace::ShaderMacroStruct>>)
```

Why does it ask me to supplu an allocator in this case?

I am using MSVC10 compiler.

**UPDATE:**

If I change string& to be const then the issue is solved.But in such a case I am forces to make a copy of the string in the function body to be able to modify it's content.The method is not called frequently but still, how to get around this in a performance wise manner?

here is the function call:

```
GLuint prog = MakeSeparableProgram(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,LoadShader("sfd/demoShader.frag"),shadersMacroList);
```

Where LoadShader() returns const std::string.

Comment: Your error message seems to have gotten mangled. Nowhere does this ask for an allocator. And I suspect even the original didn't - allocator is just part of vector's type.

Comment: Anyway, the error message probably indicates that you're trying to pass a const std::string where a reference to non-const is asked for. The real question is, why does this function take non-const references to the string and vector?

Comment: `Why does it ask me to supplu an allocator in this case?` It doesn't. The allocator argument is defaulted.

Comment: This is intentionally as I need to modify that string inside the method.

Comment: @MichaelIV: Are you trying to pass a string literal as the argument? You can't do that if you want a `std::string&`. There's your problem.

Comment: We need to see the call site, I suspect you are passing a string literal (or something else that can't be cast to `std::string&`)

Comment: That is true.If I change string& to be const then the issue is solved.But in such a case I am forces to make a copy of the string in the function body to be able to modify it's content...

Comment: @MichaelIV: That may not be a bad thing. You could just accept by value.

Comment: @MichaelIV, can you show us where you call the function, perhaps another approach can be suggested.

Comment: Do you miss a `"` in LoadShader(sfd/demoShader.frag") ?

Comment: No ,this is SO typo ...

Comment: [tag:michaeliv-so-typo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not asking you to supply an allocator; that's just the second template parameter in `std::vector`, which has a default value so you usually don't need to provide it. Note that there's no closing `>` before it; it's still part of the `vector` type.

The problem appears to be that the function requires a mutable `string` for the second argument (a non-const reference), but you're trying to pass a `const` or temporary string - although since you forgot to show us how the function is called, I can't be completely sure of that.

You probably want the second and third parameters to be `const` references; unless the function is intended to modify the arguments, in which case you'll have to pass named, mutable variables to be modified.

Comment: Now when I am looking at LoadShader() method I think you are right.It returns const string...